# shadowbox + content page showing full content in other language when not logged in

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n, modal-dialogs

I have a dual language site (English and Arabic). I am using shadowbox + content page modules to display node content (without header, footer,menu sidebars etc) in an overlay.
Everything works like a charm in both languages when im logged in but when im logged out and viewing the site in arabic I get the following strange behavior:
When I click a node to view it, the full page shows up in the overlay window which is not desired. The bigger other problem is that the content that is shown in the overlay is in English when it should be in Arabic.
Please let me know how to solve this problem or let me know if you have different approaches to achieve the same outcome.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: What's your order of language detection? How do you trigger overlay?

Comment: language order is English then arabic

Comment: i rewrote the output of a field in views:
<a href="node/[nid]?ajax_request" rel="shadowbox">[field_service_link_image_]</a>

Comment: I meant selection order set in example.comdmin/config/regional/language/configure - Like URL -> Session -> User -> Browser -> Default

Comment: I only have session enabled

Comment: Seems we have a winner ;) Enable URL and test. If it will work, then one of your modules interferes with session-based language detection.

Comment: didnt work man. I enabled URL and put in on the top as well but no use. I also cleared the cash before every test

Comment: Sorry to hear that. And now I'm out of ideas :(